# Problema para executar projeto

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, jdk

Não consigo executar meu projeto da o erro

> "com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1"

quando  eu removo *mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38* ai executa, mas o app não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, eu também tava quebrando a cabeça por conta disso. Eu resolvi da seguinte maneira: Baixa um connector com versão abaixo dessa! Estou usando o mysql-connector-java-3.0.17. Baixa ele, e coloque na pasta libs. Aqui funcionou redondo!

Comment: muito obrigado , funcionou 100% agora.